# Prove that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j+1} x^j}{j^2}$ is positive for $x \in (0,1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series

If $x \in (0,1)$, then
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j+1} x^j}{j^2} >0. $$
How to prove this in an elementary way (without using properties of the polylogarithmic function $\text{Li}_2(-x) = - \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j+1} x^j}{j^2}  $)?

Comment: For $x\in (0,1)$, you mean? (not arbitrary $x>0$). That's only an idea, but have you considered deriving the series to get a known and more "handlable" function as the derivative, something like $-\ln(1-x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x\in (0,1)$ the sequence $a_j= \frac{(-1)^{j+1}x^j}{j^2}$ ist alternating and decreasing and $a_1>0$. Thus $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_j>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the series is absolutely convergent, so all rearrangements are equal.

$\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j =\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{j+1} x^j}{j^2} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( \frac{x^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)^2} - \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)^2} \right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k$

Clearly $b_k > 0$ for each $k$, so $\sum a_j$ is a series of positive terms, therefore $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j >0$.